# Update values in IQueryable object

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have an IQueryable object and I want to update some values manually, but the changes are not reflected after the loop is executed:

```
 IQueryable<myModel> items;
 items = GetItems();   

 foreach (myModel row in items)
 {
        row.field10 = "new value";
 }

 objDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `GetItems()` method use exactly the same instance of `objDataContext` to get the items from the database? It has to use the same `ObjectContext` to keep track of changes. Another option is to use the `ToList()` method:

```
List<myModel> items = GetItems().ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, I was using the same instance of the DataContext class but the ToList() methods did the trick, thanks!, why do I need to call ToList() ?

Comment: For some reason when you're using `IQuearyable` entities are not being tracked. Maybe it's the way EF works by default or it could be some configuration setting

Comment: I am not using EF, just LINQ to SQL, but thanks anyway for the response.

Comment: Ok, the same probably applies to LINQ to SQL as well :)